# data between component vueJS2 with webpack template

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I have a problem and I can not find the solution on the internet.
I am learning to use vueJS2 with the webpack template.
I need to retrieve the data from an API

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="../src/assets/pictures/logo.png" alt="logo antadis" class="mx-auto d-block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <myCard/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import myCard from './components/my-card'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    myCard
  },
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(`https://cors.io/?http://csc_k9gko.recrutement.uize.fr/api/product.json`)
      .then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

the problem being that I have to use the API data in several other components. 
For example this one

```
<template>
<div class="myCard card fullSize ml-auto mr-auto container-fluid">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row justify-content-around">
      <myCardLeft/>
      <myCardRight/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import myCardLeft from './layout/my-card-left'
import myCardRight from './layout/my-card-right'
export default {
  name: 'myCard',
  components: {
    myCardLeft,
    myCardRight
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.fullSize {
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

But also other components kids ... I found information about vux or doing a class but without results.
I thank you in advance for your invaluable help.

Comment: What's the exact problem? And why is there a single sentence in french? ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not speak English well so I use google translation and sometimes I make mistakes to copy / paste.

Comment: the problem is that I can not pass the API data on the child components.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [VueJS Component props](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).
You need to make custom properties on your components.

Here is an exemple :

```js
Vue.component('card-component', {
    template : '<div :id="\'cardComponent\' + post.id" class="cardComponent"><h2>{{post.title}}<br><small>{{post.author}}</small></h2></div>',
    props : {
        post : {
            type : Object,
            required : true
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data : {
        posts : []
    },
    methods : {
        fetchPostData() {
            var fetchedData = [{
                id : 1,
                title : "Article 1",
                author : "John Doe"
            },{
                id : 2,
                title : "Article 2",
                author : "Jake Finnegan"
            }] // fetch your data here

            this.posts = fetchedData;
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchPostData()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
     <card-component v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" :post="post">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First if your application is not too complex, you can use `props` option to pass data from parent component to child component.

```js
// First component
const appResult = {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<h2>{{ text }}</h2>`
}

// Second component
const appContainer = {
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  components: {
    appResult
  },
  template: `<app-result :text="text"></app-result>`
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    appContainer
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app-container></app-container>
</div>
```

More over about `props`, you can check out here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

---

Or you can use Vuex for state management and complex data comunication. Vuex will help you dealing with data that will used in many component. To get started, you can configure your Vuex like this,

```js
// Vuex Store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
    text: 'Hello World'
  },
  getters: {
    text (state) {
        return state.text
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_TEXT(state, text) {
        state.text = text
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setText ({ commit }, text) {
        commit('SET_TEXT', text)
    },
    getData ({ commit }, text) {
      axios.get('/get/text')
        .then(result => {
          commit('SET_TEXT', result.data)
        })
    }
  }
})

// First component
const appInput = {
    computed: {
    text: {
        get () {
        return this.$store.getters.text
      },
      set (text) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setText', text)
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<input v-model="text">`
}

// Second component
const appResult = {
    computed: {
    text: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.getters.text
      },
      set (text) {
        this.$store.dispatch('setText', text)
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<h2>{{ text }}</h2>`
}

// Vue instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  components: {
    appInput,
    appResult
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex/dist/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <app-input></app-input>
  <app-result></app-result>
</div>
```

Quick explanation about Vuex, the `Vuex.State()` instance accept an object  which has 4 another block object inside as argument. The first one is

#### State

Here you can define a variable that will hold your data. You can set the initial variable with null. For instance if you wanna have products data, you can define it like this

```
state: {
  products: null
}
```

#### Getters

Here you can define a getters for the data. Getters is a method that accept one argument which is state and must return some value. For instance if you wanna get all the product data, you can define it like this

```
getters: {
  getProducts (state) {
    return state.products
  }
}
```

Or if you wanna get specific product, you can define a getters that return a function

```
getters: {
  getSpecificProduct (state) {
    return productId => {
      return state.products.find(product => {
        return product.id === productId
      })
    }
  } 
}
```

#### Mutations

Here you can define a mutation. Mutation is a method that will change or manipulate your state. The method is run synchronously. It  must accept two argument, the first argument is state which is the state object and the second one is payload which is the data that will be set into state.

```
mutations: {
  SET_PRODUCTS (state, products) {
    state.products = products
  }
}
```

#### Actions

Here you can define an action. Action is method that executed asynchronously, it means you can make a network request here and make a mutation whenever the data is accepted. It also accept two arguments, the first one is context which contains several handy methods that can commit a change or dispatch an action. The second one is payload which is the data that will be pass into action.

```
actions: {
  getProducts (context, url) {
    axios.get(url)
     .then(result => {
        commit('SET_PRODUCTS', result.data)
      })
  }
}
```

More over check out the Vuex documentation here, https://vuex.vuejs.org